# Two UITableViewCell with different identifier and different height in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two type of cells that I'll be using my UITableView, so I created two prototype cell with different identifier. I manuelly changed the size but when I compile and run, the two cells have same size.

Is there any way to do it through storyboard and without checking every single time

`- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

I will have around a good 100 cells at least.

**UPDATE**: in my case I have a tableview with 3 sections, the first one is small, the second and the third one are bigger.

Comment: Yeah maybe if you have some kind of pattern (lets say, every even cell is bigger), otherwise I would listen to NSAddict :D

Comment: and how would you do something computationally efficient? PS: JUST UPDATED

Comment: I personally don't like storyboards. I do this programmatically, with custom `UITableViewCell` classes. You have `IndexPath` in each `delegate` and `data-source` methods. Use the same cellIdentifier, but initialize cellForRow, with the different subclasses accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best option is to use that -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: delegate method you listed and return the height you would like.

You could assign tags to each prototype and use an if/else if conditional.

Or if you have a subclassed UITableViewCell for each prototype you could do something like

```
...
id cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCell1 class]]) {
    // return aNumber;
} else if ([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCell2 class]]) {
    // return aNumber;
} else {
    return aNumber;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the sections if what determines the height of the cell, then you can implement it like this:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    CGFloat result;
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        result = 160;
    } else {
        result = 80;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Depending on the heights that you need of course.